# MagSafe Power Cord soldering with Power Brick

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe, peripheral

How can I solder power cord back as it was? Has anyone else had the same problem? I know that Apple hardware and peripherals are very hard to "open up", so maybe some of you know some tricks about it. My power adapter looks like this:

[image: image of Apple laptop power brick with separated and fraying DC output cable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messing with a line voltage components like transformers is a huge fire hazard.

When these cords fail due to mechanical abrasion, it's common for other parts to melt or fray and I wouldn't trust myself to know if the repaired unit would be safe. I would worry the heat of soldering would do more damage to the cord close to the solder point.

Have you already called Apple and had them check if that adapter can be exchanged?

Comment: well , the problem is that i'm from Republic of Moldova (it's in Europe) and we don't have here a normal support for Apple devices, just have two or three resellers that does not care about support . Does it make sense now to call Apple in US ?

Comment: I would post on the chat later this weekend and see if someone here would call on your behalf. I have seen several DIY repair units overheat and light on fire - no joke. Not all repairs end up bad, just be careful and monitor it if you can't buy a new one. Only you know how / where it's used. In a concrete building where it would burn out safely, have at it. In a home with children, forget it.